# Indy 10 TIdIMAP4 method Retrieve issue

Tags: delphi-2010, indy

What would cause `TIdIMAP4.Retrieve(Header)` to returns False, but `LastCmdResult` returns OK?

Using `Indy 10` and `Delphi 2010`

Comment: Do you mean the `TIdIMAP4.RetrieveHeader()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving a header (or even a complete email) is a three-step process:

1. send a `FETCH` command and receive the initial response.
2. if OK, parse the requested data that follows the response.
3. read a final response. Return true if OK.

Since `RetreiveHeader()` is returning false, it must mean the final response was not OK.  But `LastCmdResult` says OK, which could only mean that the initial response was OK but the final response was not read at all.  And that condition can happen if the initial response was empty, or if parsing failed.

Without seeing the full response, it is not possible to tell you exactly why the parsing is failing.  Please capture the conversation with the IMAP server using a packet sniffer or `TIdLog...` component, and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32053840/edit) your question to include the actual response from the server.